# How to update the mute property of DOM Audio realtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, next.js

I need some help on how I can update the DOM audio in real time.

I'm trying to make the audio muted and unmuted based on the user preference,

The recording is saved in the public folder.

The audio is working fine on the first load if you set mute to be true or false, then when you try to change it, the mute props do not update.

Here is a short sample of my code, I'm using next.js.

```
import { RECORDING } from '@/constants/media.constant';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Sample() {
  const [mute, setMute] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (() => playWithAudio())();
  }, []);

  const playWithAudio = () => {
    const tryToPlay = setInterval(() => {
      // audio recording, format mp3
      const audio = new Audio(RECORDING.HELLO);
      audio.loop = true;
      audio.muted = mute;

      audio
        .play()
        .then(() => {
          clearInterval(tryToPlay);
        })
        .catch(() => console.info('User has not interacted with DOM yet.'));
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setMute(!mute)}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Sample;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is just percussion since the user needs to interact with the DOM first before the audio auto plays, if you don't do this you will receive an  "DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { RECORDING } from "@/constants/media.constant";

function Sample() {
  const [mute, setMute] = useState(false);
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAudio(new Audio(RECORDING.HELLO));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (audio) playWithAudio();
  }, [audio]);

  const playWithAudio = () => {
    const tryToPlay = setInterval(() => {
      // audio recording, format mp3
      audio.loop = true;
      audio.muted = mute;
   

      audio
        .play()
        .then(() => {
          clearInterval(tryToPlay);
        })
        .catch(() => console.info("User has not interacted with DOM yet."));
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (audio) audio.muted = !mute;
          setMute(!mute);
        }}
      >
        {mute ? "UnMute" : "Mute"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: Wow! thanks never thought I could write it like this, this saved me some time. Thanks